# Какой частью речи является слово "все"?

Tags: части-речи

Какой частью речи является слово "все" в предложении:

**Все абзацы в тексте связаны по смыслу.**

Comment: @Ариадночка, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 7):

Слово "весь" является  местоимением  во всех случаях (кроме **весь** (*устар*.) — селение).

По лексико-грамматическим признакам "весь" относится к местоименным прилагательным (оно имеет форму рода, числа, падежа и склоняется по типу прилагательных).

По семантическим признакам "весь" относится к определительным местоимениям (в эту же группу входят: *сам, самый, всякий, каждый, любой, другой*). Семантика этих местоимений более всего близка к прилагательным.

Вообще, местоимения (в отличие от существительных, прилагательных, наречий), характеризуются высокой степенью абстракции и обобщенности, и только в тексте реализуется их конкретное значение. Определительные местоимения, указывая на предмет, придают ему значение выделения или обобщения.
Что касается местоимения "весь", то оно имеет значение собирательности (*все абзацы*) или полноты охвата чего-либо.

Answer (score 2):

Все абзацы - это лексически неделимое словосочетание. Местоимение "все" не обозначает полноценного признака предмета, а только **указывает** на признак, чем и отличается определительное местоимение "весь" от прилагательного, к которому можно задать вопрос определения:
абзац какой? следующий.

Answer (score 1):

Все - определительное местоимение (весь, всякий, самый, любой и др.). Определение - не часть речи, а второстепенный член предложения, отвечающий на вопрос "какой".

[[@серж](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6)](/users/1826/%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6), я не нашла ни одного источника, где определение называлось бы частью речи. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Совершенно верно! Определение - часть речи.

Answer (score 0):

Какие абзацы - все. Все - определение.